# Given that $m$ divides $n$, show that $Z_m$ is a homomorphic image of $Z_n$.

Tags: group-theory

I know this fails if $m$ does not divide $n$ such as

Let $f:\Bbb Z_3\to\Bbb Z_2$.

$0=f(0)=f(1+2)=f(1)+f(2)=1+0=1$
Which is a contradiction

How would I go about saying that it has to always hold though?

Comment: I would start with specific examples, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

if $m \mid n$, then $n\mathbb Z \subset m \mathbb Z$, so $(\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)/(m \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z$ by the third isomorphism theorem.

One can alternatively prove  this in the following way: Consider the map $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z$ and consider the map $g+n \mathbb Z \to g+m \mathbb Z$ and apply the first isomorphism theorem (what is the kernel of the map?)

We basically just want to realize $\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z $ as a quotient.

---

A quick computation for $2 \mid 6$. (I'm going to abbreviate notation now) From this, we see that $f:\mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z$ given by $a+6 \mathbb Z \to a+2 \mathbb Z$. Only the "even" elements of $\{1,2,3,4,5,0\}$ get sent to zero, so $0,2,4$, and in particular, taking the quotient $\mathbb Z_6/\ker f \cong \mathbb Z_2$, but the kernel is really just $\mathbb Z_3$ in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this "problem to prove" is really a "problem to find" in disguise. It's saying "given that $m$ divides $n$, find a homomorphism that maps $\Bbb{Z}_n$ onto $\Bbb{Z}_m$". To define a mapping $f$ on $\Bbb{Z}_n$, what you typically do is say "let $[x]_n$ be the equivalence class *modulo* $n$ of $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ and let's define $f([x]_n)$ to be $g(x)$" where $g(x)$ can be shown to be independent of the choice of the representative $x$ within each equivalence class. In this case you take $g(x)= [x]_m$. What you have to do now is show that this is independent of the choice of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof attempt:

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_n, a\odot b=ab\operatorname{mod} m, a\oplus b=(a+b)\operatorname{mod}m$, and $f(a) = a\operatorname{mod}m$.  If $m$ divides $n$,
\begin{align*}
    f(a+b) &= (a+b)\operatorname{mod}m \\
    &= (a\operatorname{mod}m)\oplus (b\operatorname{mod}m) \\
    &= f(a) \oplus f(b)
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    f(ab) &= ab\operatorname{mod}m \\
    &= (a\operatorname{mod}m)\odot (b\operatorname{mod}m) \\
    &= f(a) \odot f(b)
\end{align*}
Hence $f:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a ring homomorphism when $m$ divides $n$.

$\Box$

Does this look reasonable?